# No Method error : Login attempts using cookies in Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

This is the functionality i used for "when a user fails to attempt login twice r thrice".

> class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
>
> prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new,
>   :create ]
>
> prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only =>
>   :create
>
> prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
>
> def new
>
> ```
> cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts] || 0
>
>    **unless params[:user][:email].blank?**
>
>   if  cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])
>
>     cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
>
>   else
>
>     cookies[:login_attempts] = 0
>
>   end
>
> end
>
> self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
>
> clean_up_passwords(resource)
>
> respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
> ```
>
> end
>
> # POST /resource/sign_in
>
> def create
>
> ```
> cookies[:email] =   params[:user][:email]
>
> self.resource =  warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
>
> if cookies[:email]
>
>   cookies[:login_attempts] = 0
>
>   set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
>
>   sign_in(resource_name, resource)
>
>   respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
>
> else
>
>   unless params[:user][:email].blank?
>
>     if   cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])
>
>       cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
>
>     else
>
>       cookies[:login_attempts] = 0
>
>     end
>
>   end
>
>   render :new
>
> end
> ```
>
> end   end

In sessions/new:

> ```
>    <% if cookies[:login_attempts].to_i >= 3 %>
>                   <div><%= raw recaptcha_tags %></div>
>               <% end %>
> ```

Entire functionality is working fine but when redirected to new,

Im getting the following error:

*NoMethodError in Users::SessionsController#new

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

The error is shown in "unless params[:user][:email].blank?" line in above controller new method.*

Please try to help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `params[:user]` returns nil object, a.k.a it does not exist. You shoudl check it first:

```
if params[:user] && cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])
```

Comment: And if user fails to login twice, i am able to show recaptcha. So at which step can i add "if valid_captcha" condition and captcha error message in my code. Its quite confusing..

Comment: That's probably new question. :)